# Pagination only showed when no category is set in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, categories, loop, pagination, paginate-links

**tldr**: On my production site only, when I set `category_name` to **any** category my pagination does not show up. Once I remove `category_name` from my `wp_query` the pagination shows up (for all posts on my site, of course).

#### The code & full problem

I have a page and set it to my page template with the following code:

```
<div>
  <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var( 'paged' )) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',  
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'category_name' => 'videos',
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);


    if ($my_query->have_posts()):

      while ($my_query->have_posts()):
        $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  
        <article>
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </article>
      <?php
      endwhile;
    endif; ?>

    <div id="my-pagination">
      <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
          'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
          'total'        => $my_query->max_num_pages,
          'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
          'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
          'show_all'     => false,
          'type'         => 'plain',            
          'prev_next'    => true,
          'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
          'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
          'add_args'     => false,
          'add_fragment' => '',
        ));
      ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

My 1 post shows up as expected (FWIW I have 33 posts in the Videos category), but the **pagination does not**. If I increase `posts_per_page` to `30` then I see 30 of my Videos posts but no pagination.

I tested this out in my local development environment and it works as expected.

#### Debugging steps

Some steps I've taken to debug:

- Exported my production database and imported it locally into a fresh install as well as imported all my files from production to local and I still do not see this issue locally
- Downgraded WordPress from 6.1.1 to 6.0.3
- I tried using `wp_reset_query` and `wp_reset_postdata`
- Tried disabling plugins 1 by 1
- Tested using the Query Loop Gutenberg block. This exhibits the same issue: as soon as I add a category filter the pagination disappears

#### Ask

How else can I debug this production only issue?

**Update 1**

Output of `var_dump($my_query->request);`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (31) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

[image: debug output 0]

[image: debug output 1]

[image: debug output 2]

**Update 2**

[image: debug screen v2]

**Update 3.5**

[image: update]

Comment: Clear your caches, keep the `'category_name' => 'videos'` in your args, then add `var_dump( $my_query->max_num_pages, $my_query->request );` right below your `new WP_Query` call, and share what the dump says. Now add `'suppress_filters' => true` to your args, reload the page, and see if the same issue persists - still no pagination showing?

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the output `float(1) string(380) " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (31) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5 "`. The output is the same whether I add the `suppress_filters` option or not.

Comment: Also for what it's worth, when I run that query in MySQL I receive back 5 post ids as expected.

Comment: So it seems `$my_query->max_num_pages` is my problem then. Changing the `total` parameter in my `paginate_links` function to _anything_ else makes the pagination show up. Are there any other debugging tips for figuring out why this wouldn't be set correctly?

Comment: Looking at the SQL, did you change the `posts_per_page` to `5`? (in the question, it's `1`) Anyway, are you certain the Videos category contains 30 or more than 5 *published* posts? If yes, then yes, that `$my_query->max_num_pages` value is wrong. Try `var_dump( $my_query );` and add the entire output to your post/question.

Comment: Yeah the 5 was just testing. I verified I have more than 30 published posts within the Videos category. I added that `var_dump` at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to know/see the value of `$my_query->found_posts`, but apparently, WPSE cut the full dump output (and maybe you should just remove that from your post?), so try this: [install this plugin](https://gist.github.com/5ally/874fee4cd86035828b003840e0572c2e) and activate it, then visit the "WPSE 414370" admin page, and follow the instructions at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I've uploaded the screenshot to the original post. I also uploaded another query I ran in the production database that gets the count of all posts within the Videos category just to make double check. The site has hundreds of posts in general (of `post_type='post'`) so the output of the debugging from the plugin seems a bit off too. I'm not sure what is going on. Thanks for all of your help by the way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Now it's getting more and more like a caching issue? Or something is filtering the `found_posts` value??  Anyway, I've updated [my plugin](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-414370/blob/trunk/wpse-414370.php), so try that revised version and let's see what the other test cases (3 & 4) say. (PS: I've deleted my gist and created a repo instead)

Comment: Uploaded another debugging summary! I also disabled WP Super Cache (and followed all deletion steps to remove any remaining files). I also made sure my host has caching turned off (unfortunately we are using Network Solutions for this site which has given me nothing but trouble). If nothing sticks out, I guess my next step would be to try to do a fresh install on another host to see what happens.

Comment: Added! And yes, 42 posts in the Videos category now (I added a few since my original post).

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, please just remove that screenshot and update your copy of [my plugin](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-414370/blob/trunk/wpse-414370.php), then capture another screenshot of the plugin admin page and add the screenshot to your post. After that, we should be able to identify the actual issue. (PS: I have deleted my gist and my previous comment )

Comment: Added the new screenshot of the plugin out. Thanks again!

Comment: Tests 4 and 5 were good, so I suggest you to do a completely clean install of WordPress (no plugins and using a default theme like 2023, and with caching disabled) on a subdomain or domain on the same server (or under the same hosting account), and install & activate my plugin there, then create some (dummy) posts and publish them under a category named Videos. Visit my plugin admin page and then share a screenshot of the page.

Comment: But actually, if all the 5 tests were good on that new site, then there's likely something wrong (which unfortunately, I'm not sure what is it) on the other site you've been testing my plugin on. But if the test results were similar in both sites, then I guess it's time to contact your hosting support for assistance..

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @SallyCJ! I'll give that a shot soon and let you know.